# Drilling machine in Star Trek

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, star-trek-reboot

If the Earth's defenses were broken then why Earthlings cannot attack the drilling machine in Star Trek when Narada starts drilling Earth to use red matter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a plot hole. There are *many* plot holes in that particular film. The idea that no one makes a suicide run at the drill is ridiculous, since it is shown to *not* possess any sort of energy shield.

Comment: Why even a suicide run? Why not launch a few missiles at it?

Comment: Good point. I'm assuming a worst-case scenario; if all else fails, you're going to die anyway, so why not at least try to blow the drill? There are, however, plenty of other ways it could have been destroyed.

Comment: And from Nero's point of view, why drill a hole at all?  All it does is make you stand still for a while. Drop the red matter on the surface, it'll create a black hole, and suck the whole planet in a slightly-less-symmetrical manner!

Comment: Great point. I wrote an article about the many plot holes in that film shortly after its release. That was one that I mentioned. It's too bad the website I wrote it on no longer exists, or I'd link to it. The red matter itself is responsible for multiple plot holes.